# is there a hint in scripture or midrash for a future nuclear war?

Tags: army-military-war, latid-lavo-future

There is a saying in chazal that 1/3 of all the troubles to befall the world will occur in the war of Gog U'Magog.

Is there any hint/allusion in scripture or midrash of an upcoming nuclear war?

Comment: Whatever it is, i'm sure it'll be found after it happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a verse in Yoel, which may be familiar from the Hagadda (or from learning Navi), which describes the apocalypse.  [Yoel 3:3-4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t1403.htm) (verse 4 included for context):

> ג וְנָתַתִּי, מוֹפְתִים, בַּשָּׁמַיִם, וּבָאָרֶץ:  דָּם וָאֵשׁ, וְתִימְרוֹת עָשָׁן.  ד הַשֶּׁמֶשׁ יֵהָפֵךְ לְחֹשֶׁךְ, וְהַיָּרֵחַ לְדָם--לִפְנֵי, בּוֹא יוֹם יְהוָה, הַגָּדוֹל, וְהַנּוֹרָא.
>
> And I will place signs in the Heavens and the Earth, blood, fire, and *timros* of smoke.  The sun will turn dark, and the moon to blood, before the coming of the great and awesome day of Hashem <sup>1</sup>

Metzudas Dovid (ibid) explains the word *timros* (תמרות) to mean that the smoke will go straight up like a palm tree (תמר).

My father-in-law (who shall remain nameless) wanted to explain the specific choice of a palm tree as the example of something that goes straight up because it spreads out at the top, and the image of the smoke would be like that of a palm tree - a plume going straight up, then blossoming out at the top.  Much like a mushroom cloud.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>If anyone wants to translate it as "the day of the great and awesome Hashem" I am fine with that- as far as I know, the modifier is vague.</sub>

Comment: is this verse talking about the war of gog u'magog? what do you mean by apocalypse?

Comment: @ray That was why I included verse 4 - it is talking about events preceding (seemingly, immediately preceding) the great day of Hashem, which is the Geula (see Metzudas Dovid to verse 4, says this explicitly).  By apocalypse, I meant the final revelation (the actual meaning of apocalypse is a revelation of something hidden).

Comment: Re your footnote: I think the trope indicate against that.

Answer (score 3):

The best source for an apocalyptic doomsday event (that I have seen) is from an ancient mystical text Sefer Heichalot (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hekhalot_literature) 5:4-5 and 6:1-2 which is cited by Rabenu Bechaya in Bereishis 44:17 (page 349 Chavel edition)

Among other fascinating and (mind-blowing) novel ideas he writes (translation mine):

> *A cloud will rise and stand over Rome for 6 months and bring down wet boils on mankind, animal, silver, gold, fruit and metal.
>   Afterwards, another cloud will rise pushing away the [first] cloud and
>   stand in its place for six months and bring down leprosy and skin
>   lesions and an assortment of plagues onto evil Rome to the point that
>   a man will offer his friend "here is Rome [for sale] for a penny" and
>   his friend will respond "I have no interest [even for a penny]."*